# Database Population in wrong Authentication Type

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-pro, database, versioning, connection

I've populated a database while connected to it as an editor with an Operating System Authentication Type.  I should have populated it while connected to the Database as the GIS administrator with a Database Authentication Type.

Consequently, After I populated it, I connected to the database as the GIS Administrator and the container is empty.

Seems like I need to push my version from one to the other and I am not sure if there is a way to do that and what that would be?

In other words: I have to push the editing Default version into the GIS Default Version.

Comment: By "populated", are you referring to putting records in the database? Because it sounds like you mean adding feature classes to the database. The database authentication type might affect who owns new features and schema changes, but has no effect on populating data (since there is only one database). Did you reconcile your changes?

Comment: Please [Edit] your question to specify the exact RDBMS in use. and the Pro version. If you loaded data as a different user, then by default you  *shouldn't* be able to see that data unless you did an explicit GRANT to do so. Unfortunately, attempting reassign ownership in a geodatabase just corrupts metadata to make the geodatabase unusable. You're going to need to reload the data.